# operators overloading in c++ , I need to store words intead of a single letter?

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

I need some help.

this is my function:

```
 class teacher
{
    public:
    char  &operator[](int i);
    protected:
    char* contents;
};
```

.cpp

```
    char & teacher::operator[](int i) 
{
    return contents[i];
}
```

main

```
    teacher s1;
cout<<"Enter names: "<<endl;
cin>>s1[1];
cout<<s1[1];
```

If I enter a word, it only returns the first character, I don't know why if I'm using a char*

Comment: Too many problems. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1870232) always helps

Answer (score 0):

If you want an array of `char*` you need to make it a `char**`. `contents[i]` is a `char`, not a `char*`.

Why not use a `vector<string>` ?

Comment: I tryed making it a char **; but it gives me an error: C2440: saying something like I can't convert 'char *' to 'char &'. And about using a vectror<string> I don't know how to use it

Answer (score 0):

You use a `char*`, but your `operator []` returns a `char&`, which is not the same as a `char*`.

If you modify the `char&` you modify only one character.

Comment: Ok I see what you mean, I get it, it's not the same.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to be doing is this:

```
class teacher {
    public:
        char*& operator[](int i);
    protected:
        char** contents;
};

char*& teacher::operator[](int i) {
    return contents[i];
}
```

Here you have an array of `char*`, i. e. C-style strings. The `[]` operator returns one of these `char*` as a reference, so that the code can change the pointer to point to some other string. This is according to the common C++ accessor idiom.

If you would choose to use `std::string`, you would just need to replace all occurences of `char*` with `std::string`.

---

Personally, however, I don't say that this approach is necessarily the best one; I have some objections against interfaces that expose the inner workings of a class like this. In this case any caller can obtain a reference to a pointer used by the class, and can use it at *any later time* to directly modify the contents of `teacher` without going through another `teacher` method. This makes it impossible to ensure *any* consistency of `contents` with the value of any other data member of `teacher`.

I try to avoid accessors in code I write, and favour methods that actually do something. That helps avoid code clutter and allows method names to name higher level operations. But that is just my opinion, many other people see it very differently.